# How can i create a responsive grid design like shown in an image?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Here is some of my CSS code which I am using to create shadow boxes inside the grid view. I tried to find HTML something like rowspan and colspan but I did't got any idea.
[image]

```
     .box{
          width: 100%;
          height: 240px;
          background: white;
          border-color: black;
          border-width: 2px;

          -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(10,0,10,1);
          -moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(10,0,10,1);
          box-shadow: -1px 2px 5px 1px rgba(10,0,10,1);
      };
```

Comment: can you please explain the issue you are facing in further detail and support your question with a codepen demo

Comment: I am trying to create a grid view using bootstrap as shown in an image. I'm novice so I don't have much idea about it. @viCky

Comment: First search/research then try something, then try some more and then post on SO seeking help. We will not make code for you from nothing. We help you debug/modify/improve your code.

Comment: I am sorry for this. Next time I will definitely do the deep search/research and try to solve the problem on my own. @Mihai T. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create columns with [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). You can try following structural.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="box h-100">Box 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box mb-3">Box 2</div>
      <div class="box mb-3">Box 3</div>
      <div class="box mb-3">Box 4</div>
      <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-3">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="box">Box 11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working great... Thank you so much. @HDP